# How to replace ICoolBarManager

Tags: eclipse-plugin, e4

I want to customize the application toolbar to my own needs. A long time ago I played around (and did some impressive customizations) with  the [`AbstractPresentationFactory`](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Findex.html&org/eclipse/ui/presentations/AbstractPresentationFactory.html).

However this extension point was removed and replaced with nothingness. (The documentation states its replacement is `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme`, but that extension point is useless without proper documentation.)

I debugged my application to the point of finding the interface `ICoolBarManager`, and lo and behold, the JavaDoc says:

> This interface is internal to the framework; it should not be implemented outside the framework. This package provides a concrete cool bar manager implementation, CoolBarManager, which clients may instantiate or subclass.

Which means I can replace the implementation of `ICoolBarManager` somehow (why else would I need to instantiate or subclass `CoolBarManager`?). A possible point for doing so is `ApplicationWindow#createCoolBarManager2(int)`, but I'm not sure where and if I ever create an `ApplicationWindow`.

The simple question is: How do I replace the implementation of `CoolBarManager`?

Comment: Eclipse 4 doesn't use `ApplicationWindow`. The current cool bar manager (`CoolBarToTrimManager`) delegates the UI portions of the code to the `ToolBarManagerRenderer` which can be changed using the Eclipse 4 renderer factory.